# Improving InnoDB settings - causes unexplainable locks

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have InnoDB on dedicated server and from time to time a simple join query (normally very fast) causes an infinite wait and dies after 30 seconds.

The query looks like "SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN orders_products USING(code)"

This is EXPLAIN:
[image]

I am convinced InnoDB is f this up and I don't know why, but it's when more people access the script at the same time.
I am NOT doing any updates or inserts in that script, so it makes no sense.

It could be that somewhere is a script that does a concurrent write and maybe then this main script fails? I have no clue. I never had issue on MyIsam and I don't use transactions.

**Can we change settings somehow to fix this?**

We have a big server, but neither the admin or I know how to set this properly.

Suggestions are welcome.

This is current settings:

```
Variable_name
Value
innodb_adaptive_flushing
ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm
10.000000
innodb_adaptive_hash_index
ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions
1
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay
150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval
5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock
OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog
OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl
OFF
innodb_api_trx_level
0
innodb_autoextend_increment
64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode
1
innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval
3600
innodb_background_scrub_data_compressed
OFF
innodb_background_scrub_data_interval
604800
innodb_background_scrub_data_uncompressed
OFF
innodb_buf_dump_status_frequency
0
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct
100
innodb_buffer_pool_filename
ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances
2
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_populate
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size
2147483648
innodb_change_buffer_max_size
25
innodb_change_buffering
all
innodb_checksum_algorithm
CRC32
innodb_checksums
ON
innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor
HIGH_CHECKPOINT
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled
OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency
0
innodb_compression_algorithm
zlib
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct
5
innodb_compression_level
6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max
50
innodb_concurrency_tickets
5000
innodb_corrupt_table_action
assert
innodb_data_file_path
ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir
innodb_default_encryption_key_id
1
innodb_default_row_format
compact
innodb_defragment
OFF
innodb_defragment_fill_factor
0.900000
innodb_defragment_fill_factor_n_recs
20
innodb_defragment_frequency
40
innodb_defragment_n_pages
7
innodb_defragment_stats_accuracy
0
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache
OFF
innodb_disallow_writes
OFF
innodb_doublewrite
ON
innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm
BACKOFF
innodb_encrypt_log
OFF
innodb_encrypt_tables
OFF
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age
1
innodb_encryption_rotation_iops
100
innodb_encryption_threads
0
innodb_fake_changes
OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown
1
innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold
600
innodb_file_format
Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check
ON
innodb_file_format_max
Antelope
innodb_file_per_table
ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout
1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
2
innodb_flush_method
O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors
1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops
30
innodb_force_load_corrupted
OFF
innodb_force_primary_key
OFF
innodb_force_recovery
0
innodb_foreground_preflush
EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF
innodb_ft_aux_table
innodb_ft_cache_size
8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print
OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword
ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size
84
innodb_ft_min_token_size
3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize
2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit
2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree
2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size
640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table
innodb_idle_flush_pct
100
innodb_immediate_scrub_data_uncompressed
OFF
innodb_instrument_semaphores
OFF
innodb_io_capacity
200
innodb_io_capacity_max
2000
innodb_kill_idle_transaction
0
innodb_large_prefix
ON
innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm
fcfs
innodb_lock_wait_timeout
50
innodb_locking_fake_changes
ON
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog
OFF
innodb_log_arch_dir
./
Variable_name
Value

innodb_log_arch_expire_sec
0
innodb_log_archive
OFF
innodb_log_block_size
512
innodb_log_buffer_size
16777216
innodb_log_checksum_algorithm
INNODB
innodb_log_compressed_pages
ON
innodb_log_file_size
268435456
innodb_log_files_in_group
2
innodb_log_group_home_dir
./
innodb_lru_scan_depth
1024
innodb_max_bitmap_file_size
104857600
innodb_max_changed_pages
1000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct
75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm
0.001000
innodb_max_purge_lag
0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay
0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups
1
innodb_monitor_disable
innodb_monitor_enable
innodb_monitor_reset
innodb_monitor_reset_all
innodb_mtflush_threads
8
innodb_old_blocks_pct
37
innodb_old_blocks_time
1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size
134217728
innodb_open_files
5000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only
OFF
innodb_page_size
16384
innodb_prefix_index_cluster_optimization
OFF
innodb_print_all_deadlocks
OFF
innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info
OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size
300
innodb_purge_threads
1
innodb_random_read_ahead
OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold
56
innodb_read_io_threads
4
innodb_read_only
OFF
innodb_replication_delay
0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout
OFF
innodb_rollback_segments
128
innodb_sched_priority_cleaner
19
innodb_scrub_log
OFF
innodb_scrub_log_speed
256
innodb_show_locks_held
10
innodb_show_verbose_locks
0
innodb_simulate_comp_failures
0
innodb_sort_buffer_size
1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay
6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc
ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked
OFF
innodb_stats_method
nulls_equal
innodb_stats_modified_counter
0
innodb_stats_on_metadata
OFF
innodb_stats_persistent
ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages
20
innodb_stats_sample_pages
8
innodb_stats_traditional
ON
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages
8
innodb_status_output
OFF
innodb_status_output_locks
OFF
innodb_strict_mode
OFF
innodb_support_xa
ON
innodb_sync_array_size
1
innodb_sync_spin_loops
30
innodb_table_locks
ON
innodb_thread_concurrency
0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay
10000
innodb_tmpdir
innodb_track_changed_pages
OFF
innodb_undo_directory
.
innodb_undo_logs
128
innodb_undo_tablespaces
0
innodb_use_atomic_writes
OFF
innodb_use_fallocate
OFF
innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit
ON
innodb_use_mtflush
OFF
innodb_use_native_aio
ON
innodb_use_stacktrace
OFF
innodb_use_sys_malloc
ON
innodb_use_trim
OFF
innodb_version
5.6.46-86.2
innodb_write_io_threads
4
```

Comment: what does EXPLAIN query tell you?

Comment: @Martin I added screenshot in the post... is that any useful?

Comment: I don't get it... I get all rows from SELECT, store them in Array and move on with it...
I will choose specific columns, might help little, but it's still bad.
Query takes 0.02 seconds, but at some point keeps hanging and 5 connections wait for this same SQL, so they die.

Comment: When the query gets stuck run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and post it here. Your query will be listed in "TRANSACTIONS" and it will show what locks it's waiting for. It may be useful to collect more data with `pt-stalk --no-stalk --iteration 1` because a next question would be what transaction holds that lock.

Comment: @akuzminsky - thank you, t checked, but nothing is listed... is it because it's not a transaction?

Comment: All queries against InnoDB tables create a transaction, even if it is implicitly as autocommit. The `SELECT` query you show should not cause any locking or wait for locking, unless (a) there is an exclusive metadata lock held on the table, or (b) if you use SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level.

Comment: One possibility I can think of, since the query uses a temp table — is it using disk space for the temp table, and does the filesystem where temp tables are stored have enough free space? A 100% full filesystem causes problems for MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just split the query to 2 queries (many rows/conditions) and it works now.

Probably was difficult query (despite the fact it was quick) and when having more hits, it stalled. Idk.